# how to set maximum version when creating a firefox addon xpi?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons

I'm trying to create an xpi package for a firefox addon through cfx tool. Once I ran "cfx xpi" command in the directory where my files are, an xpi package is generated. If I tried to install this package on current version of firefox (9.0), I get an error message saying this addon is not compatible with 9.0 version of firefox. How do I make my addon compatible with newer version of firefox ?

More info:
1) I'm very new to add-on development so I'm just using the reddit-example given along with the sdk kit. 
2) I extracted the xpi file to a folder and the install.rdf inside shows a maximum version of 8.* . I changed this to 9.* . How do I make cfx take this install.rdf instead of what ever it is defaulting to ?
3) I installed the addon sdk when 8.0 version of firefox was the current version.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of the SDK are you using? If you use SDK version 1.3 or the online builder the addons you create should be compatible with Firefox 9. You can download the latest version of the SDK here:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/jetpack/addon-sdk-1.3.zip

Comment: +1 - You just need the latest version. Here's what 1.3 of the SDK generates: `<em:minVersion>9.0</em:minVersion>` and `<em:maxVersion>12.0a1</em:maxVersion>`

Answer (score 1):

once you upload the addon to [AMO](http://addons.mozilla.org) you can change the supported versions there.